# I am using image sequence in angular which works fine on Iphone chrome but lags on iphone safari

Tags: angular, mobile-safari

> 1. Following is my code which includes the html,CSS and the ts file for the component. When the user scrolls the image in series is being
>    changed and looks like a video playing on  scroll.But the same
>    scenario keeps on lagging on iPhone safari.
> 2. Does this lag happen on all safari devices ?
> 3. Is there any solution to the same problem ?

```js
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-end-slider",
  templateUrl: "./end-slider.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./end-slider.component.css"],
})
export class EndSliderComponent implements OnInit {
  frameCount = 330;
  frameCountBottle = 330;
  currentImage = new Image();
  context: any = null;
  imageWidth = 0;
  imageHeight = 0;
  iVisible = false;
  WH = 0;
  textTop = 0;
  textTop2 = -100;
  textTop3 = -100;
  textTop4 = -100;
  opacityTop = 0;
  opacityTop2 = 0;
  opacityTop3 = 0;
  opacityTop4 = 0;
  orientation = true;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.preloadImages();
    const canvas: any = document.getElementById("can-slider-4");
    console.log(window.innerWidth);
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    console.log(window.innerHeight);
    this.WH = window.innerHeight;
    this.textTop = this.WH;
    this.textTop2 = this.WH;
    this.textTop3 = this.WH;
    this.textTop4 = this.WH;
    this.context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.currentImage.src = this.currentFrame(1);
    const ratio =
      this.currentImage.naturalWidth / this.currentImage.naturalHeight;
    this.imageWidth = canvas.width;
    this.imageHeight = canvas.height; 
   
    const self = this;
    this.currentImage.onload = function () {
 
      var scale = Math.max(
        canvas.width / self.currentImage.width,
        canvas.height / self.currentImage.height
      );
     
      var x = canvas.width / 2 - (self.currentImage.width / 2) * scale;
      var y = canvas.height / 2 - (self.currentImage.height / 2) * scale;
      self.context.drawImage(
        self.currentImage,
        x,
        y,
        self.currentImage.width * scale,
        self.currentImage.height * scale
      );
   
    };
  }

  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event.target"])
  scroll(e: any) {
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const canvas: any = document.getElementById("cc-4");
  

    this.iVisible = false;

    if (canvas.offsetTop < html.scrollTop) {
  
      this.textTop = this.WH - (html.scrollTop - canvas.offsetTop) / 5;
      this.opacityTop = (1 - this.textTop / this.WH) * 2;
      if (this.textTop < this.WH / 2) {
        this.textTop = this.WH / 2;
      }
  
      const scrollTop = html.scrollTop - canvas.offsetTop;
      const maxScrollTop = 3000; 
      const scrollFraction = scrollTop / maxScrollTop;
    
      const frameIndex = Math.min(
        this.frameCountBottle,
        Math.ceil(scrollFraction * this.frameCountBottle)
      );
      if (frameIndex <= this.frameCountBottle) {
        console.log(frameIndex);
     
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          this.updateImageBottle(frameIndex);
        });
      } else {
      }
    } else {
      this.textTop = this.WH;
      this.textTop2 = -1000;
      this.textTop3 = -1000;
      this.opacityTop2 = 0;
      this.opacityTop3 = 0;
    }
  }

  currentFrameHigh = (index: any) =>
    `/assets/images/can/Can_Splash_Scene_2_A.57.${(index + 1).toString()}.jpg`;

  currentFrameBottleHigh = (index: any) =>
    `/assets/images/bottle/Rotate_water_bottle.54.${(
      index + 1
    ).toString()}.jpg`;

  currentFrame = (index: any) =>
    `/assets/images/Can_landing_with_transition/can_landing_transition_0_${index.toString()}.jpg`;


  currentFrameBottle = (index: any) =>

    index <= 99
      ? `/assets/images/Home_page_last_anim/bottle 2_000${index.toString()}.jpg`
      : `/assets/images/Home_page_last_anim/bottle 2_00${index.toString()}.jpg`;

  preloadImages = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.frameCountBottle; i++) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.src = this.currentFrameBottle(i);
    }
  };

  updateImageBottle = (index: any) => {
    this.currentImage.src = this.currentFrameBottle(index);
 
  };

  updateImage = (index: any) => {
    this.currentImage.src = this.currentFrame(index);

  };
}
```

```css
.is-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.canvas-container-4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3000px;
}

.canvas-container-4 canvas {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

}

.container-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px !important;
  text-align: left;
}

.canvas-text-2 {
  position: sticky;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
  font-size: 8vh;
  left: 0px !important;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  .canvas-container canvas {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;

  }

  .canvas-text-2 {
    position: sticky;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5vh;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas-container-4" id="cc-4" (scroll)="scroll($event)">
    <canvas id="can-slider-4"></canvas>
</div>
```